# Axis scale will not change with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot with matplotlib with the following x-values:

```
[1.1e19, 5.6e31, 1.1e32, 1.6e32, 2.2e32, 2.8e32]
```

However, because my first x-value is so small relative to the others, matplotlib gives me the following
[autoscaled x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I8LJ.png).
My first point lies on the y-axis. I'd like for this point to be more visible.

I've tried:

```
ax.set_xlim(1e16, 1e36)
ax.set_xlim(xmin=1e16, xmax=1e36)
ax.set_xbound(lower=1e16, upper=1e36)
```

to no avail. I am able to change the upper bound of my x-axis, but never the lower bound.

**Edit:**
For those asking for example code, this is what I'm running:

```
dose = np.array([1.1e19, 5.6e31, 1.1e32, 1.6e32, 2.2e32, 2.8e32])
counts = np.array([46, 31, 15, 16, 14, 13])

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dose, counts, 'ob-')
ax.set_xlim(1e16, 1e36)
#ax.set_xlim(xmin=1e16, xmax=1e36)
#ax.set_xbound(lower=1e16, upper=1e36)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could use logscale or even scale your data points (linear or nonlinearly) to better visualize them. To visualize them as they are, `ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])` alone should just work fine. I dont know why do you have `ax` and `ax1` though. You should show minimal complete code if you want further more detailed help.

Comment: I don't want to use a log scale because only my first value is small.

Comment: I tried each method individually. `ax1` was a typo.

Comment: Maybe there is some bug with matplotlib at those large values. Anyway, if you could put a minimal example we could use to reproduce the error we might have better luck at helping with it.

Comment: Added an edit with example code

Comment: Thanks! I'm on the go right now but will play with it later if not yet answered. Adding a minimal example is the easiest way of getting help (or discvering a bug) in SO.

Comment: I think you're actually making the axis narrower as `0 * 1e32` is 0, so moving it to 1e16 moves the lower limit to the right. 

Further `1.1e19 / 2.8e32 = 4e-14` so that value is always going to be imperceptibly just off the lower limit of the axis unless you go to a log scale.

Comment: following @PaulH if your upper limit is 1e32 then:
1e31 gets plotted at 0.1   
1e30 gets plotted at 0.01   
1e29 gets plotted at 0.001   
...   
1e16 gets plotted at 0.0000000000000001   

independent of what your lower boundary is.   

so it isn't a bug, you will always be putting that point imperceptibly near the y-axis even if the lower bound is 1e16... i'll edit my answer below to update this line of thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, Bad news...

Your code actually is working.  if you look at the values `ax.get_xlim()` you will see the boundaries you set.

(Using Spyder/Ipython for some quick tests)

The following two screenshots are your plot... a linear axis and a log axis.
[image: linear example]
[image: log example]

So it looks like matplotlib has a limit to the size/scale of the range you can view using a linear axis.  All data less then three or four orders of magnitude smaller than your upper boundary get compressed so that look to be right on the y-axis

Bad news is that I cannot provide an actual solution to this challenge... just that you aren't doing anything incorrect.  Maybe its a bug? I would suggest opening an issue on the [matplotlib github page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) to see if there is a more complex solution or one of the developers has an idea.

**Note: Not a bug... but leaving link to development team anyways

following @PaulH if your upper limit is 1e32 then:
1e31 gets plotted at 0.1
1e30 gets plotted at 0.01
1e29 gets plotted at 0.001
...
1e16 gets plotted at 0.0000000000000001

independent of what your lower boundary is.

so it isn't a bug, you will always be putting that point imperceptibly near the y-axis even if the lower bound is 1e16...

Answer (score 2):

Ommiting the limits setting would be an option. The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dose = np.array([1.1e19, 5.6e31, 1.1e32, 1.6e32, 2.2e32, 2.8e32])
counts = np.array([46, 31, 15, 16, 14, 13])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dose, counts, 'ob-')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

produces this figure:

[image]

which looks fine to me.

Of course you can change the axis limits, if you wish to. E.g. using

```
ax.set_xlim(xmin=-1e32, xmax=5e32)
```

would result in

[image]